# Tab-panel dinamicos

Tags: php, html

hola tengo la duda de como se puede hacer un tab-panel dinamico donde se puedan poblar las tablas dependiendo de los datos de la bd, pude poblar 2 tablas pero estas me traen los mismos datos en ambas, lo cual no es correcto porque dependiendo de la nave a la que se llama estas debería poblarse con esos datos, adjunto un fragmento de mi codigo:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs m-2  nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist">
                <?php
                    foreach ($naves as $nave) { ?>
                    <li class="nav-item mx-2">
                        <a class="nav-link small" href=".tabPanelNaves" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" value="<?php echo $seDistNave?>"><?php echo $nave?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul> 

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade tabPanelNaves">
                    <div class="jumbotron p-2 bg-white shadow rounded-lg">
                        <table class="table table-sm table-bordered" id="tablehPlanProgramaCargaNaves" data-page-length='7'>
                            <thead class="bg-success text-light">
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="small">FECHA</th>
                                    <th class="small">CLIENTE</th>
                                    <th class="small">ORIGEN</th>
                                    <th class="small">DESTINO</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>    
                            <tbody>
                                <?php 
                                    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT programacarga.idProgramaCarga, tiponaveoperacion.seDistNave, naves.nombre AS nombreNave,
                                    programacarga.fechaEmisionPrograma, programacarga.fechaPrograma, programacarga.origen, programacarga.destino, programacarga.idCliente, clientesprogramacarga.nombreCliente, programacarga.programaCargaObs
                                    FROM programacarga
                                    JOIN tiponaveoperacion ON tiponaveoperacion.seDistNave = programacarga.seDistNave
                                    JOIN naves ON naves.seDistNave = programacarga.seDistNave
                                    JOIN clientesprogramacarga ON clientesprogramacarga.idCliente = programacarga.idCliente
                                    WHERE programacarga.seDistNave = '$seDistNave'");

                                    $query->execute();
                                    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                    foreach ($result as $row) {

                                        $seDistNave = $row['seDistNave'];
                                        $fechaEmisionPrograma = $row['fechaEmisionPrograma'];
                                        $idProgramaCarga = $row['idProgramaCarga'];
                                        $fechaPrograma = $row['fechaPrograma'];
                                        $nombreNave = $row['nombreNave'];
                                        $idCliente = $row['idCliente'];
                                        $cliente = $row['nombreCliente'];
                                        $origen = $row['origen'];
                                        $destino = $row['destino'];
                                        $programaCargaObs = $row['programaCargaObs'];
                                ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="small"><?php echo $fechaPrograma ?></td>
                                        <td class="small"><?php echo $cliente?></td>
                                        <td class="small"><?php echo $origen?></td>
                                        <td class="small"><?php echo $destino ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: Buenas, Diego, bienvenido al sitio. En el código que muestras me da la sensación de que falta otro bucle foreach para que se generen varios tabs.

Comment: Buenos días @RubioRic con el bucle foreach que tengo me va generando los tabs dependiendo de las naves que tengo en la bd, eso hasta ahora me ha funcionado, solo que no me trae los datos  ingresados correspondientes de la nave seleccionada

Comment: Buenas, Diego, si usamos como referencia el código que has puesto, yo veo dos foreach: (1) Líneas 3-7 que te construye los enlaces; (2) Líneas 34-53 que te construye una fila por cada resultado de tu segunda consulta. ¿Cómo se generan distintos tabs? Quizás me estoy perdiendo algo. Por otro lado no veo de donde sale el valor inicial de $seDistNave.

Comment: @RubioRic Hola, si he implementado mal algunas cosas $seDistNave la estaba Llamando de otra tabla, lo cual estaba erroneo, por ahora he logrado solucionar mi problemas, muchas gracias por tu tiempo.